# toLocaleString() don't show zero

Tags: javascript

Hello i have a question about:

```
Number.prototype.toLocaleString()
```

Trouble is that when we use "toLocaleString()" method it will not show latest maximumFractionDigits value if there was "0".

```
var i = 50456.40345345;
i.toLocaleString('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits: 2})
// It will return "50,456.4".
// I want to see "50,456.40".
```

How can i do that?

Comment: How about using `minimumFractionDigits` too?

Comment: Thanks Teemu, i forgot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [**`minimumFractionDigits`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```js
var i = 50456.40345345;
i = i.toLocaleString('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2});
document.write(i);
```

Although you are specifying the `maximumFractionDigits`, the numbers don't necessarily have 2 fraction digits, so that's why you need to specify `minimumFractionDigits`.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to use minimum and maximum :)